# Encrypt the stored procedure in sql to improve the security of database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to improve the security of my database, so I want to know what I should do.

And how I can encrypt the stored procedures.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What makes you think this will improve the security of your database?

Answer (score 6):

You will need to write a procedure that decrypts the stored procedure and execute it - anyone with access to the database will also be able to access this procedure, so you gain nothing by encrypting a stored procedure.

There are well established practices regarding [database security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648664.aspx) - follow them.

Some of them are:

- Give minimal permissions
- Use different user logins
- Do not use sa

Answer (score 2):

Use `WITH ENCRYPTION`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ProcedureName]
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

      SELECT ...

END
```

Never encrypt development procedures though as you cannot decrypt these easily!